# Duplicate data in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to know how create stored procedure for inserting data like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertActor
    @fname VARCHAR(15),     
    @sname VARCHAR(20), 
    @age INT = NULL,
    @gender VARCHAR(6) = NULL            
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    INSERT INTO Actor (fname, sname, age, gender) 
    VALUES (@fname, @sname, @age, @gender)
END;
```

But I have problem with duplicate date I can add 10 times the same actors. Can you help me?

Comment: Please be more specific - what is your desired result?

Comment: Use  `IF Not Exists` to determine whether to insert the data or not. But what if actor's have the same names?

Comment: If some combination of data is supposed to be unique, e.g. only one actor with a given `fname` and `sname` is allowed, then you have more work to do. What would happen if an `update` changed a name so that there was a duplicate? A _unique constraint_ on the table could prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in the beginning should accomplish what you need:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Actors WHERE  fname = @fname AND sname = @sname)
    RETURN;
```

Or you can do more complex insert if you prefer this way:

```
;WITH ToInsert AS
(
    SELECT @fname AS fname,  @sname AS sname, @age AS age, @gender AS gender
)
INSERT INTO Actors
    (fname, sname, age, gender)
    SELECT I.fname, I.sname, I.age, I.gender FROM Actors A RIGHT JOIN ToInsert I ON  A.fname = I.fname AND A.sname = I.sname
    WHERE T.fname IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask about the second solution I dont understand exactly  why is there I.gender...of T.sname?

Comment: It should have been both "I", my bad :)

Comment: Ou sorry, I was no my goal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF Not EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Actors WHERE  fname = @fname AND sname = @sname and age=@age and gender=@gender)
    INSERT INTO 
Actor( 
    fname,      
    sname, 
    age,
    gender
) 
VALUES( 
    @fname,     
    @sname, 
    @age,
    @gender)
```

Alternatively you can set the combination of the data you dont want to repeat as Unique or Primary key and your code will throw an exception. 
Then you can handle the exception.

Comment: Thank you very much :D It helps me.

Comment: @Maca Happy to help :) 
Since you are new here. If you find answers that are good and helpful, you should upvote them (even if it is not your question), so best answers go on the top, and these answers can help other people.
If it is your question, in addition to upvoting (you can upvote more than 1 answer) you can also accept 1 answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Using `top 1` without `order by` in an `exists` subquery is an interesting optimization.